# Alexa Skill - How to Retrieve Slot Value in Lambda Function

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa Skill with one Intent that includes a Slot with several possible values.

My slot is defined with `"name" : "Channel"`, `"type" : "LIST_OF_CHANNELS"`, and values

1. iqram
2. ingrid
3. phil
4. clyde

How do I retrieve the uttered **slot value** to use in my Lambda function? It's the *"retrieve value of slot from utterance part"* I'm looking to have answered. Thanks so much.

```
 // retrieve value of slot from utterance     
 var c = intent.slots.Channel.value; 

 // append value to end of URL that references API
 fetchEnseParse("/channel/" + c, function(body) {

 // continuation of this function is below
```

Answer (score 13):

`var c = this.event.request.intent.slots.slotname.value`

This should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That little piece of code unblocked me! Could you provide some link to documentation where I can read more? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In the event that your lambda receives you can find it here...

```
{
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "intent": {
      "name": "YourIntentName",
      "slots": {
        "slotname": {
          "name": "slotname",
          "value": "HERE!"
        }
      }
    },
    "locale": "en-US"
  },
}
```

The event is passed to your lambda handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var c = this.event.request.intent.slots.Channel.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the below worked:

```
event.currentIntent.slotDetails.<slot-name>.originalValue
```

where `slot-name` is `Channel`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say u said to alexa, the word "**coin**" and you programmed this as a synonym of **bitcoin** (the main objectname).

Now u can get 2 results.

First: You get the original value "bitcoin", which is the original value/matched value

Or second: You get the spoken value "coin"

**First (bitcoin):**

```
this.event.request.intent.slots.<yourslotname>.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name
```

**Second (coin):**

```
this.event.request.intent.slots.<yourslotname>.value
```

*Careful: yourslotname is not the Slottype! It's the name*

Comment: Not sure why -1 here? I have same cse right now as well. I extended one of AMAZON lists (AMAZON.Room) and I added some synonyms for "small room" ("computer room", "game room") so when Alexa will deliver me value to my Lambda it can deliver "computer room" and I do not plan to implement synonym matching on Lambda level so I would exactly try to get value from "resolutionsPerAuthority"

Comment: Thank you @MariuszKarpicki 
I seriously dont know why I received a -1 here, but I am lucky that I could help ✌

Comment: here I found more detailed description, in case someone else may want to read more: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/cfbd2f5e-c72f-4b03-8040-8628bbca204c/alexa-skill-teardown-understanding-entity-resolution-with-pet-match

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to simply look at `this.event.request.intent.slots.<yourslot>.value`

This value has only the 'utterance' and it may not be what you are looking for

I had to deeper into the object and look at the resolutions object and check the authority object which has a status of `code=="ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"`

Here's my java code which worked - you can pretty much do the same in Nodejs

```
private String getSlotValue(JSONObject s)
{

    String utterance="";
    String choice ="NA";

  try {

        if(s.has("option"))
        {

        JSONObject optionObject =s.getJSONObject("option");

        utterance =optionObject.getString("value");

        JSONObject resolutionsObject =optionObject.getJSONObject("resolutions");



        JSONArray resolutionsPerAuthority =resolutionsObject.getJSONArray("resolutionsPerAuthority");

        for (int i = 0; i < resolutionsPerAuthority.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject auth = resolutionsPerAuthority.getJSONObject(i);

            if (auth.getJSONObject("status").getString("code").equals("ER_SUCCESS_MATCH") )

                {
                if(auth.has("values"))
                    {
                    JSONArray  values = auth.getJSONArray("values");

                    choice=values.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("value").getString("id");
                    }
                }           

        }

        }

    return choice;

    }
  catch (Exception e) {
   choice="Error "+e.getMessage();
   return choice;
   }
}
```